# How to render word or pdf doc in Django template

Tags: django

`

```
<div class="modal-body">
   {% if forms|length == 1 %}
       {% for form, html in forms.items %} 
           {% ssi html %}
       {% endfor %}
```

`
snapshot for rendering html document
I want to render pdf/doc file which has been uploaded through some form filed in a modal. The above code works for html files. I want to do the same for pdf/doc file.

Comment: Please, be more specific about what you need. For example, provide sample code related to your question. This question seems too vague.

Comment: I have edited the post